# Modificar registro segun fecha de input

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas compañeros estoy tratando de resolver un requerimiento del cliente y es que un registro de mi tabla cambie de estado según la fecha indicada de plazo, si alguien puede orientarme a resolver este tema ya que con temas de scripts o eventos de mysql no me he manejado aun

Esta es mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que cuando el registro llegue a la fecha plazo y no se haya modificado su estado, su estado pase automáticamente a "Fuera de plazo"

Comment: Creo que para este caso te conviene tener números en los estados (0 finalizado, 1 pendiente 2 tardío) y en el lenguaje que estés programando el sistema (no estoy seguro si sql te deja tener condicionales de ese estilo) cada vez que se cargue esa función primero se actualice tipo ``` actualizar_asuntos() ``` y ya su propia lógica (si fecha plazo < fecha hoy update Estados where ID =?) [estoy proponiendo una solución  muy general]. Podrías poner que lenguaje es para proponerte una respuesta que solucione tu problema?

Comment: Estoy utilizando php con mysql